# Tablet pc handwriting recognition: can one program with it?

Tags: tablet-pc, tablet, pen-tablet

I'm thinking that it may be useful to be able to use handwriting recognition to write code. I can't seem to find evidence of people doing this. So, my questions are: is it possible, has someone done it, if so, what did they think?

Answer (score 0):

You'll spend way too much time fighting to get it to recognize symbols and variables names that aren't in its dictionary.  Windows 7 has amazing recognition for words that are in its dictionary, but as soon as you deviate from that, you'll end up having to correct every second symbol you enter.

It might be possible to create an IDE from scratch that combines intellisense with the handwriting recognition, but I've certainly never heard of one.  There has been some work with voice recognition in this direction: http://www.renaissance.co.il/VSSpeech.aspx

Comment: The link that you've provided does look interesting though.

Comment: @Tunji Hmm, I'm not sure this would actually speed up coding. Especially because most IDEs nowadays auto-complete lines and input for-loops, empty methods and the like automatically.